# Downloading files code gets unexpected 404 error

Tags: vb.net, file, download, http-status-code-404

My code downloads files in loop but after the last file downloads it keeps downloading files that aren't there. Website shows redirect and 404 error.

I'm new with visual basic so I'm asking for help here.

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(strFullUrlDownload, strFullSavePath, False, 1000)
```

404 error
redirect

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim strMainUrl As String = "http://jixxer.com/123/"
    Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim dtDate As String = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim strSlash As String = "/"
    Dim strPdf As String = "pdf"
    Dim strDot As String = "."
    Dim strPage As String = "page"
    Dim strPageNbr As String = 1
    Dim intCounter As Integer = 1
    Dim strPageCounter As String = String.Format("{0:000}", intCounter)

    Dim strSavePath As String = "D:\dls\title1\"

    Dim strFullSavePath As String = strSavePath & strPageCounter & strDot & strPdf
    Dim strFullUrlDownload As String = strMainUrl & dtDate & strSlash & strPdf & strSlash & strPage & strPageNbr & strDot & strPdf

    Do Until strPageCounter = 200

        ' Downloads the resource with the specified URI to a local file.

        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(strFullUrlDownload, strFullSavePath, False, 1000)
        intCounter = intCounter + 1
        strPageNbr = strPageNbr + 1
        strPageCounter = String.Format("{0:000}", intCounter)

        strFullSavePath = strSavePath & strPageCounter & strDot & strPdf
        strFullUrlDownload = strMainUrl & dtDate & strSlash & strPdf & strSlash & strPage & strPageNbr & strDot & strPdf

    Loop

End Sub
End Class
```

```
Try

    'TRY to download the file using https first...
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(New Uri("https://" & ServerAddress & WebLogoPath & Convert.ToString(RowArray(0)) & ".png"), Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\" & AppDataFolder & PCLogoPath & Convert.ToString(RowArray(0)) & ".png", "", "", False, 500, True)
Catch ex_https As Exception
    'Unable to locate file or write file
    'If the operation timed out...
    If (ex_https.Message = "The operation has timed out") Then
        'Re-TRY to download the file using http instead, as a time out error may indicate that HTTPS is not supported.
        Try
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(New Uri("http://" & ServerAddress & WebLogoPath & Convert.ToString(RowArray(0)) & ".png"), Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\" & AppDataFolder & PCLogoPath & Convert.ToString(RowArray(0)) & ".png", "", "", False, 500, True)
        Catch ex_http As Exception
            'Most likely, the file doesn't exist on the server. Either way, we cannot obtain the file so we need to perform the same action, 
            'which is handled outside of this Try block.
        End Try
    Else
        'This is most likely a 404 error. Either way, we cannot obtain the file (and the connection is not timing out) - so
        'we need to perform the same action, which is handled outside of this Try block.
    End If
End Try
```

I just put the counter at 200 to test and make sure it works. But I know I need a way to quit on error but not sure how to code it yet. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many documents are stored in that remote directory, you have to handle the exception when a page is not found.
It's always possible to receive [WebExceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webexception) when a resource is requested from a site, so you should handle this case anyway.

I suggest to use the [WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient) class directly instead of `Network.DownloadFile()`, which may be handy if you want to show a predefined UI of the progress (when it's possible), but using WebClient directly, lets you perform the  download asynchrounously if you need it to, using the async/await pattern and the [WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfiletaskasync) method.

Another suggestion: use a method to download those files, so you can call it from anywhere in your code. You can use a class or a module to store your methods, so you don't clutter your UI and you can also easily reuse these classes or modules in different projects, just including in a project the file that contains them.

Your code could be modified as follow (synchronous version):

You need to pass to the **`DownloadPdfPages`** method the remote base address: `http://jixxer.com/123`, the Path where the files are store (**`filesPath`**).
The third and fourth parameters are optional:
- If you don't specify a **`resourceName`**, `Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` is assumed,
- If you don't specify a **`startPage`**, it will default to `1`, converted in `page1.pdf` (the example here asks to start from page `3`).

Note: I'm using [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings) here:  **`$"page{startPage + pageCount}.pdf"`**.
If your VB.Net version doesn't support it, use [String.Format()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format) instead.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim numberOfPages = DownloadPdfPages("http://jixxer.com/123", "D:\dls\title1", "", 3)
    If numberOfPages > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show($"Download completed. Number of pages: {numberOfPages}")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Download failed")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function DownloadPdfPages(baseAddress As String, filesPath As String, Optional resourceName As String = "", Optional startPage As Integer = 1) As Integer
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceName) Then resourceName = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim resourceAddr = Path.Combine(baseAddress, resourceName, "pdf")
    Dim pageCount = 0
    Dim client = New WebClient()
    Try
        Do
            Dim documentName = $"page{startPage + pageCount}.pdf"
            Dim resourceUri = New Uri(Path.Combine(resourceAddr, documentName), UriKind.Absolute)
            Dim fileName = Path.Combine(filesPath, documentName)
            client.DownloadFile(resourceUri, fileName)
            pageCount += 1
        Loop
    Catch ex As WebException
        If ex.Response IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim statusCode = DirectCast(ex.Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode
            If statusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound Then
                Return pageCount
            End If
        ElseIf ex.Status = WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError AndAlso ex.Message.Contains("404") Then
            Return pageCount
        Else
            ' Log and/or ... 
            Throw
        End If
        Return 0
    Finally
        client.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

Asynchronous version, using the **`WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync()`** method.
Just a few changes ae necessary, note the **`Async`** keyword added to both the Button.Click handler and the **`DownloadPdfPagesAsync()`** method.
The **`Await`** keyword is then used to wait for a method to complete, without blocking the UI:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim numberOfPages = Await DownloadPdfPagesAsync("http://jixxer.com/123", "D:\dls\title1", "", 3)
    If numberOfPages > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show($"Download completed. Number of pages: {numberOfPages}")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Download failed")
    End If
End Sub

Private Async Function DownloadPdfPagesAsync(baseAddress As String, filesPath As String, Optional resourceName As String = "", Optional startPage As Integer = 1) As Task(Of Integer)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceName) Then resourceName = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim resourceAddr = Path.Combine(baseAddress, resourceName, "pdf")
    Dim pageCount = 0
    Dim client = New WebClient()
    Try
        Do
            Dim documentName = $"page{startPage + pageCount}.pdf"
            Dim resourceUri = New Uri(Path.Combine(resourceAddr, documentName), UriKind.Absolute)
            Dim fileName = Path.Combine(filesPath, documentName)
            Await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(resourceUri, fileName)
            pageCount += 1
        Loop
    Catch ex As WebException
        If ex.Response IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim statusCode = DirectCast(ex.Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode
            If statusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound Then
                Return pageCount
            End If
        ElseIf ex.Status = WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError AndAlso ex.Message.Contains("404") Then
            Return pageCount
        Else
            ' Log and/or ... 
            Throw
        End If
        Return 0
    Finally
        client.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for the sample code.  It's amazing but to say the least I'm lost and can't follow what is going on in there.  Do you know of any resources I can study about this so i can try to wrap my head around it and begin to write it this way?


Thanks again,

Willy

Comment: The best thing you can do is to read the notes, substitute your code with this one, put a break point (usually pressing `F9`) on the first line of code of the method you want to test (`DownloadPdfPages` or `DownloadPdfPagesAsync`) and then run it. Follow the code step by step and see what happens. This code is pretty standard, you can find code samples related to the WebClient class everywhere. You also need to add error handling for other possible conditions (Path not found, disc full or removed, Internet connection down etc.). If you want to make it a production code, that is.